# not able to change the location path in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a login form and I am simply trying to change the path once the register button is selected. For some reason the login button works but the register button does not. When I click it nothing happens. Even if I put an alert inside the register controller nothing comes up which tells me that the controller function is not being executed. I am new to angular js and not sure if I understand **ng-click** and **$location.path** well

here is my code for the register button:

```
<button ng-click="register()" class="btn btn-default" id="lefty" >Register</button>
```

and my code for the controller and the route provider in app.js:

```
$routeProvider.when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterController'

      });



app.controller('RegisterController', function($scope, $location) {
        $scope.register = function() {
        $location.path('/register');
    }
});
```

I simply expect once register button is clicked to be able to go to the /register path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the Register button on the login page. As per your code `register` method is inside `RegisterController` so it is not available on the Login page. Move this method to your login page controller it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $window:

```
    app.controller('RegisterController', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.register = function() {
    $window.location = '#/register';
}
});
```

Comment: The $location object doesn't change effective the current path. It only prepare or capture data for any url